# How to properly index match using dates between two different tabs

Tags: excel, indexing

I am trying to automate a report, but I am running into some errors when trying to use index match to report data for matching dates between to excel sheets.

In the pictures below, I want the table to be populated when data is pulled in another tab and the dates in the table match the ones in the tab where the data is pulled. For instance, where it says 'Mar-18', i want to report the data from the 'ACT STND PRODUCTION' line in the SPI Performance tab where it says '03.2018'.

***Graph tab***

[image: Graph tab]

***SPI Performance tab***

[image: SPI Performance tab]

The first tab is called Graph and the second is called SPI Performance. Right now , I have `=INDEX('SPI Performance'!C6:C14,MATCH('SPI Performance'!$B$10,'SPI Performance'!$B$6:$B$14,0),MATCH(Graph!D26,'SPI Performance'!K5,0))` for the Mar-18 box in the table, but i am getting an error.

Thank you for any feedback you may have!

Comment: Value not available error. I can get the correct number just from leaving out the last match statement, but it's literally just for that table that's pulled right now and will not be correct if the data changes

Comment: `MATCH(Graph!D26,'SPI Performance'!K5,0)` is looking at just one value? with `0` as third argument, you will get an error if there is no match... probably `'SPI Performance'!C5:ZZ5` or something like this should do the trick.... also the initial range `'SPI Performance'!C6:C14` should have more than one column like `'SPI Performance'!C6:ZZ14`

Comment: with that line, i was just hoping to match one date from the Graph tab with that same date in the SPI Performance. I tried changing the range to 'SPI Performance'!C5:Z5 but that didn't do it for me

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula to see if the cell will populate correctly:

```
=INDEX('SPI Performance'!$C$10:$K$10, MATCH('Graph'!D26,'SPI Performance'!$C$5:$K$5,0))
```

If you enter that formula in cell D27 on the "Graph" Sheet then drag it to the right through column M the answer should populate based on the ACT STND PRODUCTION line in the 'SPI Performance' Sheet.

You can alter the ranges $C$10:$K$10 and $C$5:$K$5 as needed depending on how large your range needs to be.